# Laravel 5 Package Scheduled Tasks

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a package that has some scheduled tasks - is there way of registering / publishing them without affecting the base applications already set scheduled tasks?

I don't want to overwrite the `App/Console/Kernel.php` as the base application may already have it's own scheduled tasks etc.

Comment: Why not just add your own 'PackageKernel.php'?

Comment: As far as I understand there's only one HTTP Kernel and one Console Kernel that's initiated.

Comment: Yes you're right abt that I tried it sorry

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You certainly can, all through the power of some basic object-oriented programming!

### Step 1: Create Your Package's "Kernel" Console Class

Let's create a Kernal class within your package's Console directory where we will be extending `App\Console\Kernel`.

```php
<?php
namespace Acme\Package\Console;

use App\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    //
}
```

### Step 2: Add the `schedule` method

Since we are extending the App Console Kernel, we'll want to add the relevant schedule method and call the parent class' implementation of it. This will ensure that any previously scheduled tasks carry through.

```php
<?php
namespace Acme\Package\Console;

use App\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the package's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        parent::schedule($schedule);

        //
    }
}
```

### Step 3: Add your scheduled tasks

Now you may add your own scheduled tasks per normal.

```php
$schedule->command('')->daily();
```

### Step 4: Register It!

We'll want to bind the class to the container, and `make` it within our package's service provider's `register` method:

```php
$this->app->singleton('acme.package.console.kernel', function($app) {
    $dispatcher = $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher::class);
    return new \Acme\Package\Console\Kernel($app, $dispatcher);
});

$this->app->make('acme.package.console.kernel');
```

---

That should be all that's required!

Some things to take into consideration with this though:

1. Be up-front that your package has these bundled tasks. Developers don't like surprises (especially when it concerns tasks being automatically ran on their server).
2. Along with the first point, not every one will have the required cronjob set up on their server. They'll need to do this before your package's tasks will run automatically.
3. Provide a config option to **disable** the package's tasks from being auto registered, and documentation on how developers can register it themselves based on their own needs.

Comment: Why shall we call parent::schedule ? It replaces the native console Kernel ?

Comment: Though the solution works with a single package but implementing the same in multiple packages works only for the package which is registered in the last. https://laravel.io/forum/08-30-2016-scheduled-tasks-in-packages-with-v52 Any advice to fix this.

Answer (score -2):

In your package service provider, do this:

```
/** @var array list of commands to be registered in the service provider */
protected $moreCommands = [
    \My\Package\CommandOne::class,
    \My\Package\CommandTwo::class,
    \My\Package\CommandThree::class,
];
```

Then in your boot() method of the service provider do this:

```
$this->commands($this->moreCommands);
```

Very good question, btw. Had me searching through the Laravel API docs to find the answer, and when I found it I implemented it in one of my own packages.

Comment: That's already documented in various places - I've got the commands registered fine, but what I'm asking is how to register the actual `$schedule->command('some:command')->daily()` from within the package.