# Laravel - How to run schedule in multiple packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

currently, i'm working with project that has some modules which need to run schedule job.

I want to take schedule job into Kernel of each module (not `Kernel` in `app/Console` directory).

I did like this [Laravel 5 Package Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834681/laravel-5-package-scheduled-tasks) but it only run on 1 module. The others did not run.

Can anybody please help me! Thanks

My source code has structure like this:

```sh
app
|   Console
|   |   Commands
|   |   |   Command.php
|   |   Kernel.php
bootstrap
...
Module
|   Module 1
|   |   Console
|   |   |   Commands
|   |   |   |   Command11.php
|   |   |   |   Command12.php
|   |   |   Kernel.php
|   Module 2
|   |   Console
|   |   |   Commands
|   |   |   |   Command21.php
|   |   |   |   Command22.php
|   |   |   Kernel.php
```

Comment: did you register commands with ServiceProvider?

Comment: @NguyenHungThai I did it before.

Comment: could you show me your code register commands?